# jQuery xml2json pluggin does not work in IE

Tags: jquery, xml, json, internet-explorer

i'm using a jQuery xml2json pluggin (http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/) to parse xml to json but it doesn't work fine in IE. I wonder if someone could help me handling this.

Here's a xml sample that I want to convert to json: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1' standalone='no'?> <context> <object objid="228" author="johnDoe" creation-date="2012-10-24 22:55:09.0" last-updated="2012-10-24 22:55:09.0" type="objectType" name="ojectTest" availability="public" status="active"> <attribute-set> <attribute attid="399" name="Geo-Location" value=" 12.1234567_-32.1234567" time="2012-10-24 22:56:10.0"/> </attribute-set> <relation-set> </relation-set> </object></context>`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe IE has problems with your single quotes. Try to use only double quotes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ...
```