# Json cant get an value in MSIE

Tags: json, internet-explorer, null, nullreferenceexception

I`ve an json-Array and in all browser it works but not in MSIE

$JsonData.entry[i].content.properties.Date.text

I get the error: The property "Date" of an undefined or null object can not be accessed (translated by myself)

Browsers like FF & C run this part successfully and get the date. But the IE fails. 
Any idea?

The $JsonData is an object which is build by an jquery plugin called "xml2json", because the result of an get-request is an xml-document returned by an SharePoint listdata.svc-webservice. The $JsonData looks korrekt for me. The tree-structure is well formed and with firebug I can navigate manually to the $JsonData.entry[i].content.properties.Date.text.
The Path is like this: entry>0>content>properties>Date>text

Comment: Can you add some more details on how the json data is retrieved (ajax call) and the structure of it? What is the type of your $JsonData? Maybe it is considered as a string that you need to transform as object? $.parseJSON($JsonData), console.log(typeof $JsonData)

Comment: Sorry...I edited the initial post.

Comment: Instead of accessing your keys directly using the dot (.) notation try to use $JsonData['entry'][i]['content']['properties']['Date']['text']. It is possible that 'Date' is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Which version of IE exactly?

Comment: This changes nothing.

Comment: I use the IE9 and IE10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717771/jquery-xml2json-pluggin-does-not-work-in-ie ... it looks like my problem in located in the xml2json-plugin for jquery.